# How to calculate summation values from multiple JTextFields using loop in java

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am trying to making a calculator.
Here the user can add `multiple` `JTextFields` to take his/her desired input with just one button click.

Now I want that the user will take the input in `multiple` `JTextFields` added by him and on clicking the Result button will show the sum of all. But I am always getting `0` as output.

Code:

```
public class Button extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton btnAdd;
private JButton btnResult;
private JTextField resultField;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Button frame = new Button();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Button() {
    initComponents();
}

static JTextField field = null;
//static JTextField fields[] = new JTextField[10];
private static int y = 0;
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

int ans, sum = 0;

private void initComponents() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 527, 414);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
    btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            field = new JTextField();
            field.setBounds(45, y += 60, 284, 32);
            field.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
            contentPane.add(field);
            contentPane.revalidate();
            contentPane.repaint();
        }
    });
    btnAdd.setBounds(170, 341, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnAdd);
    
    btnResult = new JButton("Result");
    btnResult.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                arr.add(field.getText());
                sum += Integer.parseInt(arr.get(i));
            }
            resultField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    });
    btnResult.setBounds(383, 306, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnResult);
    
    resultField = new JTextField();
    resultField.setBounds(361, 275, 129, 20);
    contentPane.add(resultField);
    resultField.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

**Please help how can I find the correct output?**

Comment: Could you share the overall code?

Comment: Your best bet is to show us compilable and runnable code. We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, a [mre]. Please check out the link for the details of this useful construct.  Again, if the code is very small and still is compilable and runnable more people will be able to fully understand the code and the problem and help provide a decent answer.

Comment: I have Edited and give the code perfectly so that everyone can now understand easily.

Comment: Your code does not compile for me as there is a method, `initComponents()` that is called but is not present in your posted code.

Comment: And you have an `ArrayList<String>` which won't work. You need an `ArrayList<JTextField>`, and then add each JTextField on creation to this list, so that you can extract the text from each JTextField when the result button is pushed.

Comment: I Hope this time you will face no problem to run it. I mistake to copying the codes that time. sorry.

Comment: Again, you need an ArrayList of all JTextFields created, and you're not yet doing this. Side note to avoid null layouts and setBounds.

Comment: I change the `ArrayList` into `ArrayList<JTextField>` and then inside `Result` button i do this `arr.add(field);
     sum += Integer.parseInt(arr.get(i).toString());`
but it still show `0`

Comment: you need to 1) add the text fields to the array list as you create it. 2) get the ***text*** from the jtextfield in the for loop. 3) then parse that text. Note: better to not even use a JTextField but rather a JSpinner that uses a SpinnerNumberModel so that non-numeric Strings can't be entered.

Comment: btw: __never-ever__ do any manual sizing/positioning - that's the __exclusive__ task of a LayoutManager (which must not be set to null, obviously :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Again, when you create a data-entry text field, add it to the GUI and add it to an `ArrayList` of the data entry field type.
- Then in the result button's ActionListener, iterate through this list using a for loop.
- Inside of the for loop, get the entry field, get its text (via `.getText()` if using a JTextField), parse it to number via `Integer.parseInt(...)`, and add it to a sum variable that is initialized to 0 prior to the for loop. Then display the result after the loop.

Also,

- Best to use JSpinners that use a SpinnerNumberModel such as `JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 1));` instead of JTextField for number entry. This will limit the user to entering numbers only, and won't allow non-numeric text entry, a danger inherent in your current design.
- Having to add your entry fields by button may be an over-complication
- But if it is necessary, then best to add the spinners (or text fields if you must) to a JPanel that uses a proper layout manager, such a `new GridLayout(0, 1)` (variable number of rows, 1 column) and then add that to a JScrollPane so that you can see as many fields as has been entered.
- If using a JSpinner, then you don't even need a "calculate result" button, since if you add a ChangeListener to each JSpinner, you can calculate the result on the fly whenever a spinner has had its data changed.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Button2 extends JPanel {
    private List<JSpinner> spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
    private JButton resultButton = new JButton("Result");
    private JButton addEntryFieldBtn = new JButton("Add Entry Field");
    private JTextField resultField = new JTextField(6);
    private JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));

    public Button2() {
        resultField.setFocusable(false);
        resultButton.addActionListener(e -> calcResult());
        resultButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        addEntryFieldBtn.addActionListener(e -> addEntryField());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.add(addEntryFieldBtn);
        topPanel.add(resultButton);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
        topPanel.add(resultField);
        
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        centerPanel.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(centerPanel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    private void calcResult() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (JSpinner spinner : spinnerList) {
            sum += (int) spinner.getValue();
        }
        resultField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }

    private void addEntryField() {
        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 1));
        spinner.addChangeListener(evt -> {
            calcResult();
        });
        
        fieldPanel.add(spinner);
        spinnerList.add(spinner);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Button2 mainPanel = new Button2();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```